# Prisma Postgresql URL connection - Error: P1001: Can't reach database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I am having trouble connecting to my database created from a Docker container. I'm getting this error **Error: P1001: Can't reach database**, and I assume it has something to do with the fact that the database is in the container while Prisma is on my machine.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: fynansus-db
    env_file:
      - .env
  pgadmin:
    image: 'dpage/pgadmin4'
    container_name: fynansus-pgadmin
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

pdadmin works correctly and can connect with db.

and my .env

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_USER=root
POSTGRES_DB=fynansus
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root:password@db:5432/fynansus"

PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@gmail.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=123
```

I tried change the host of the url to ( localhost, db, fynansus-db, container-ip), but none of them work, i also tried to expose the port 5432 but dont work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Prisma from your host machine (for development I suppose), you will have to set the "ports" section of the docker-compose service. Then you will have to use "localhost" in your DATABASE_URL.

```
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: fynansus-db
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT-5432}:5432
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Before you try to connect with Prisma, make sure everything is running (docker compose logs) and that you can connect with psql.